# Trouble retrieving images with Alamofire, some images load, some don't (SWIFT)

Tags: iphone, swift, firebase, alamofire, imageshack

So I'm kind of stuck here. I have a mobile app that has a "feed" using a TableView and it's populated with pictures, descriptions, and likes from firebase. I use ImageShack for the image upload API, and having the imgLinks grabbed from there (with alamofire). the images are uploading find, and on my ImageShack panel, the pictures look great. So I know it's not firebase, and not imageshack's fault, but most pictures won't even load, they are just white boxes, and I can confirm that imageUrl != nil, so it's definitely a request problem with Alamofire.
Here is my Alamofire GET request code
          if post.imageUrl != nil {

```
        if img != nil {
            self.deckImg.image = img
        } else {

            request = Alamofire.request(.GET, post.imageUrl!).validate(contentType:     ["image/*"]).response(completionHandler: { request, response, data, err     in
                if err == nil {
                    let img = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    self.deckImg.image = img
                    FeedController.imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: self.post.imageUrl!)
                } else {
                    print(err.debugDescription)
                }
            })
        }
    } else {
        self.deckImg.hidden = true

    }
```

Also, I can confirm that it's not hiding the image, because when self.deckImg.hidden = true, I have the rows adjust height, and I can also see that that's never called, because it never even hit that breakpoint. So it's simply something to do with Alamofire's get request .. what is it :(

Comment: First, I suggest you look into using [AlamofireImage][1], which provides image loading infrastructure on top of Alamofire, including it's own caching and image decoding. 

Aside from that, we really need more info in order to help you. Do you get data back? Is turned into a proper UIImage?

  [1]: https://github.com/alamofire/alamofireimage

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is the problem, as I was stuck myself for days on end.
I take it you are using a custom tableViewCell VC and that within the function that binds the data you put something like:

```
self.deckImg.image = nil
```

and then check if there is a cached image, if not download it with alamofire
after you check that the post.imageUrl != nil {}, you have to **unhide** the self.deckImg:

```
if post.imageURL != nil
{
    self.deckImg.hidden = false

    if img != nil 
    {
        self.deckImg.image = img
    } 
    else 
    {
        request = Alamofire.request(.GET, post.imageUrl!).validate(contentType:     ["image/*"]).response(completionHandler: { request, response, data, err     in
            if err == nil {
                let img = UIImage(data: data!)!
                self.deckImg.image = img
                FeedController.imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: self.post.imageUrl!)
            } else {
                print(err.debugDescription)
            }
        })
    }
}
 else
{
    self.deckImg.hidden = true
}
```